# await fetch returns a 404 in NextJS, only await post works

Tags: next.js

In NextJS the following POST call works via `await post`,

```
const payload = {
   'param1': param1,
   'param2': param2
};

const response = await post<any,any>("/app/action", payload);
```

But I wanted to execute this the traditional way as `await fetch` with a POST param and `JSON.stringify()` and that results in a **404 (Not Found)**, for some reason:

```
const response = await fetch("/app/action", {
     method:'POST',
     headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify(payload)
});
```

Why is that? There's nothing wrong with the controller, it's a Spring-based `@PostController` and it works with the first example.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to use `await fetch` with URL `/api/action`, you should
  make the request in a client component. Make sure use add a `use client;` at
  top of your file.
- If you want to use `await fetch` in a server component, Make sure to
  add the full URL like `http://localhost:3000/api/action`.